# Getting the date of an NSDate date from within a category

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, categories

I add a category to NSDate as follows:

```
@interface NSDate (ElapsedDays)

-(unsigned long) elapsedDays: (NSDate *) theDate;

@end

@implementation NSDate (ElapsedDays)

-(unsigned long) elapsedDays:(NSDate *)theDate
{
  self.[???]
}

@end
```

In main, I declare NSDate as follows:

```
NSDate *today=[NSDate date];
```

Now in the `elapsedDays` implementation, how can I access the date that `NSDate` was initialized with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The receiver of the message `elapsedDays` is `self` in the method implementation scope.

For example:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSDate (ElapsedDays)

- (NSInteger)elapsedDaysSinceDate:(NSDate *)theDate;
@end

@implementation NSDate (ElapsedDays)

static const NSInteger SecondsPerDay = 86400;

- (NSInteger)elapsedDaysSinceDate:(NSDate *)theDate {
    NSTimeInterval interval = [self timeIntervalSinceDate:theDate];
    return interval/SecondsPerDay;
}

@end

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMddyyyy"];

        NSDate *date1 = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"01012012"];
        NSDate *date2 = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"12312012"];

        printf("Date difference = %ld",[date2 elapsedDaysSinceDate:date1]);
    }
}
```

Prints `Date difference = 365` to the console.

**EDIT (using Gregorian calendrical calculations)**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSDate (ElapsedDays)

- (NSInteger)elapsedDaysSinceDate:(NSDate *)theDate;
@end

@implementation NSDate (ElapsedDays)

- (NSInteger)elapsedDaysSinceDate:(NSDate *)theDate {
    NSTimeInterval interval = [self timeIntervalSinceDate:theDate];
    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components = [gregorian components:NSDayCalendarUnit
                                        fromDate:theDate
                                          toDate:self 
                                                 options:0];
    return [components day];
}

@end

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMddyyyy"];

        NSDate *date1 = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"01012012"];
        NSDate *date2 = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"12312012"];

        printf("Date difference = %ld",[date2 elapsedDaysSinceDate:date1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for the correct answer of using self. But the implementation isn't going to take account of changes to Daylight Savings. You should be using date components.

Comment: Ah yes, and of all days to forget that!